# Is it bounties? or bountied?

Tags: bug, user-interface

The tabs on SP.SE, has a link to questions which has open bounties.

Is "Bountied" written by mistake or a typo? Or I am just overthinking :)

[image]

Comment: Bountied sounds fine to me.  I see what you mean though, "Click here for questions on which bounties are offered" would also be possible.  Perhaps either word could be used.

Answer (score 4):

I think **Bountied** is correct word.

As the tabs are showing question, so it will be like **Bountied Questions** (on which bounties are offered) and not **Bounties Questions**.

Comment: As the person who made this change... this is pretty much the case, yes.